# How to use breakpoint in python without using IDE features

Tags: python, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

It will great help if you can explain with code example or any useful resource.

Comment: Check this: [Debugging Python without an IDE](https://pythondebugging.com/articles/debugging-python-without-ide)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the in-built `pdb` library.

```
import pdb 
a = 10
pdb.set_trace()
print(a)
```

So what it would basically do is, stop the program after line 2 is executed. and from there you would have command line access to the code with is execute above the `set_trace()` is added.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `breakpoint()` method is part of the python language now. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/

If you are using an earlier version of python then you can have the same functionality by importing pdb by `import pdb` at the top of you file and `pdb.set_trace()` where you want to be able to inspect variables.

When you are dropped into the pdb shell you type `h` to see what commands are available.